# VB.Net equivalent of ^ operator in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

What is the equivalent operator in VB.Net for ***^*** (this is for C#)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Xor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx) operator is the equivalent.

> Performs a logical exclusion on two Boolean expressions, or a bitwise exclusion on two numeric expressions.

The C# [`^`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operator is:

> Binary ^ operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, ^ computes the bitwise exclusive-OR of its operands. For bool operands, ^ computes the logical exclusive-or of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if exactly one of its operands is true.

---

If you mean the VB.NET [power operator `^`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh100ckf.aspx):

> Raises a number to the power of another number.

It doesn't have a C# equivalent - you need to use [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

---

There are a few lists comparing syntax and features of both languages - I like [this one](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) and [this one](http://aspalliance.com/625).

Answer (score 1):

Xor  check VB.Net equivalent for C# operators [here](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Xor Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Performs a logical exclusion on two Boolean expressions, or a bitwise
>   exclusion on two numeric expressions.

```
result = expression1 Xor expression2
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Pow` should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double Math.Pow(double x, double y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean ^ as in [bitwise XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)? In which case it would be [Xor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx)